# How to hide/unhide div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a Checkbox in my index.html file as

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.isChecked, new { id = "isChecked" })  

<div id='Shipping'> 
      <p> Some textboxes here </p>
</div>
```

I would like to hide the sipping div if the checkbox is checked and unhide if not checked. And i would like it to be dynamic. How do i do that?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of thousands of solutions to this problem all over the internet. This question is just lazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to bind a `change` event to the checkbox and check it's `:checked` selector to determine if the div needs to shown or hidden.

```
<script>
$().ready(function(){
  $('#isChecked').change(function()
   {
     $(this).is(":checked") ? $("#Shipping").show() : $("#Shipping").hide();
   }).change(); // optional
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd first bind to the check box's `change` event:

```
$('#isChecked').change(function() {
    //...
});
```

*Within* that event handler, you'd then show/hide the `div` based on the state of the check box.  Possibly something like this:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#Shipping').show();
} else {
    $('#Shipping').hide();
}
```

Of course, you'll also want to set an initial value.  A simple way to accomplish both would likely be to wrap the logic in a function:

```
var toggleDiv = function () {
    if ($('#isChecked').is(':checked')) {
        $('#Shipping').show();
    } else {
        $('#Shipping').hide();
    }
}
```

Then call it from the event handler above:

```
$('#isChecked').change(toggleDiv);
```

And also when the page loads:

```
toggleDiv();
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
$('#isChecked').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).removeClass("hide");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("hide");
    }
});
```

css:

```
.hide{ display:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='Shipping' class='hide'> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#isChecked').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#Shipping").hide()
    } else {
      $("#Shipping").show()
    }
});
```